# How can I get the main color of Windows 10 in Electron apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've used an app built by Electron called Knote, and there was a feature that allows you to set the main color of the application to the main color of Windows 10 (but it seems that the feature was gone now). So I wondered that, **is there any APIs or functions that allows Electron apps to get the main color of Windows 10?**

p.s. I'm a student from China and I don't know whether my English is good or not... So please, do not care about any grammatical mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron's [systemPreferences API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences) has a bunch of methods like `getAccentColor()`, `getColor()`, etc. Some are compatible with Windows, macOS or both.
I just tested some on Windows 10 and they seem to be working well. I suggest that you take a look at these.